# lxml build on Solaris 10

Tags: python, lxml

Please can you help and advise with a problem with python 2.6.6 and lxml Solaris 10 build?

Installation instructions:
www.sunfreeware.com/download.html

direct link to the file:
http://www.sunfreeware.com/ftp/pub/freeware/sparc/10/lxml-2.2.8-sol10-sparc-local.gz

```
[rainier]/usr/apps/openet/bmsystest/relAuto/RAP_SW> python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Oct 12 2010, 15:25:47) [C] on sunos5
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lxml
>>> from lxml import etree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ld.so.1: python: fatal: relocation error: file /opt/csw/lib/python/site-packages/lxml-2.2.8-py2.6-solaris-2.10-sun4u.egg/lxml/etree.so: symbol xsltDocDefaultLoader: referenced symbol not found
>>>
```

Thanks

---

Mismatch of version: this is identical to the advise I got independently and I can only pass it onto the installer as I am developer and do not have root privilege.
Thanks for such a quick response!

Comment: Have you tried downgrading lxml to see?  Have you tried installing with the source?  At this point, you don't know if it's Solaris or lxml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this before. Think it was due to a mismatch between two versions of python. 
I think it was that python was calling /usr/local/bin/python, but lxml had compiled against a different version of python (found in /bin/python or something like that)